# Objective-C Showing a view controller on another view controller programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, controller

I've got one problem. I have a viewController1 in which I click a button. When I hit this button, I want it to show another view controller (viewController2) on viewController1 (viewController2 is a little transparent).
I'd like to do this programmatically.
I tried this but when I hit the button nothing happens:

```
Notification *newView = [[Notification alloc]initWithNibName:@"Notification" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
```

I renamed some variables to make it clearer. Thanks for answers!

EDIT: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, I want viewController2 to be ONTOP of viewController1

Comment: How would you like to show it? Should it come in with a navigation (e.g. sliding in from the bottom or from the right of the screen)? Also, can you please check if you `navigationController` is initialised with: `NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);`, if it's `nil` then make sure that your view controller has access to a `navigationCotnroller`.`

Comment: It doesn't matter how it appears, the best would be without an animation. Also the output isn't nil.

Comment: Is the code in your button method executed? If you want viewController1 to be visible underneath viewController2, then this method will not work. Pushing a view controller causes the old controller's view to be pushed off the screen and removed from the window's view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:-

```
 Notification *newView = [[Notification alloc]initWithNibName:@"Notification" bundle:nil];
  [self presentViewController:newView  animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: If this is not working for you, you are doing something substantially wrong in your code.